# Already imported required modules in appmodule.ts but still getting Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'

Tags: html, angular, typescript, forms, angular-reactive-forms

Added both reactive and forms module in appmodule.ts but still getting this error

Unable to solve Can't bind to formGroup since it isn't a known property of form.

I have already tried all the solutions
**Component.html**

```
<form class="mb-5 container" [formGroup]="financeOverdueInvoiceForm">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <label class="custom-label w-100">ID </label>
                <input type="number" nbInput class="w-100 custom-text-font-size" name="vendor_id" formControlName="vendor_id" >
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <label class="custom-label w-100">Currency </label>
                <input type="number" nbInput class="w-100 custom-text-font-size" name="invoice_id" formControlName="invoice_id" >
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <button nbButton status="primary" size="medium" type="submit" (click)="financeCaseSubmit();">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

**component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule, FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormControl, Validators, FormArray } from '@angular/forms';
@Component({
  selector: 'ngx-finance-case-overdue-invoices',
  templateUrl: './finance-case-overdue-invoices.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./finance-case-overdue-invoices.component.scss']
})
export class FinanceCaseOverdueInvoicesComponent implements OnInit {
  financeOverdueInvoiceForm: FormGroup;
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.financeOverdueInvoiceForm=this.fb.group({
      vendor_id : new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
      invoice_id: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),

    })
   }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
  financeCaseSubmit(){
    console.log("1");
  }
}
```

Comment: the "modules" (ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule) should be imported in the app.module.ts **not** in component (really in the module where you component is declared -else you're using standalone components-). NOTE: if you use formBuilder, you use `this.fb.group({vendor_id:['',Validators.required],...})` see that **not** use new FormControl

Comment: Hi Eliseo, I have removed new form control for thi.fb.group but still not working

Comment: has you import the ReactiveFormsModule and the FormModule in your app.module.ts?. I know it's a bit complex, but remember the "modules" are imported in module, not in components. (you need import and add to the array "imports", see the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/architecture-modules)

Comment: Already imported them but still the error exists. In my project already they used this kind of form setup but there is no issue there. I have created this form as new component